# How can I pass a double or any other random type from Java to C++ via socket?

Tags: java, c++, sockets, networking, client-server

I'm developing a client-server app where the server is C++ and the client is Java.

To communicate them, I use sockets. Now, I can transfer sucessfully Strings via the socket with this:

Client side:

```
public void serializeAndSendMessage(String msg) {
    try {
        os.write( msg.getBytes() );
        os.flush();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Server side:

```
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        recvbuf[iResult] = 0; //set the end of the msg
```

How can I pass other data, like a Double or an Int? Is it possible to get a Double into a String, and then convert it back in the C++ server from char to Double?

Thanx.

Comment: Hh, I'm afraid the only 100% reliable way to do this is "as text" (and than `sscanf` in C or so).

Comment: @Vyktor that isn't reliable either. Try it with a NaN or infinity.

Comment: @AlanStokes ha ha, good one, do you have anything more reliable? Because sending binary data (as 4 bytes directly representing float/int variables) doesn't feel like a way to go.

Comment: @Vyktor Actually I think binary is more reliable. But you do have to worry about endianness and representation differences at the endpoints. And that's a pain, so use a library to do it for you - as Dirk suggests.

Comment: Definitely agree that binary is the way to go.  You're guaranteed to always have 8 bytes and lose no data, whereas with a string and floating point numbers you are guaranteed neither.

Comment: Yes, thats true, but, if i have understood well, what ProtocolBuffers do is transform random data structures into a byte array, that you can send via the network as bytes, without loss of data, and then, turn it back into your data structure in the receptor. I think this is what im gonna do, it seems pretty easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *really* want something like [**Google ProtocolBuffers**](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) which takes care of the **serialization** and **deserialization** of **arbitrary** data structures in a **cross-platform and cross-language** manner.

There are other libraries providing an alternative to ProtoBuf such as [**Apache thrift**](http://thrift.apache.org/) (and some of which add the networking which ProtoBuf is missing).   That said, ProtoBuf is a fine choice as it is mature, used by Google themselves and has Java and C++ as core languages with first-tier support.

Comment: Thanx, i will take a look at that protocols, it may be the solution :)

Comment: I have been reading a bit about those protocols, and i think that they may work perfecly, because they already come with a way to transform your data structures into Strings, so i can use my code to send then, and then get them back as structures, so i think this is the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

On the Java side, do something like this to get your bytes:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(double value) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(value);
    return bytes;
}

...

os.write(toByteArray(1.234));
os.flush()
```

Then, on the C++ side, you can get it back out like this:

```
double received;
memcpy(&received, recvbuf, sizeof(double))
```

Comment: You're ignoring endianness, which is never a good idea. Not to mention assuming the C++ end uses the same floating point representation - admittedly these days that's fairly safe.

Comment: It's true.  But as long as he can detect endianness on both sides, and then reverse the array accordingly, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I think that could do the trick too, but that endianness could be a problem, its true, i think im gonna go with the protocolBuffers, but thanks for the code, its always a way to learn :)

Comment: Yeah.  If you know that endianness is guaranteed to be the same on all clients and servers, this would be easier to integrate into what you've got.  That said, the last time I did something like this my clients were embedded PPC systems and my servers were x86 boxes....seems like you rarely get that ideal situation in the real world.